# try catch notice

Tags: php

Почем try catch не ловит ошибки уровня notice? а именно он не ловит не существования индекса массива.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261051/how-to-catch-an-undefined-index-e-notice-error-in-simpletest

Comment: @L.Vadim ссылка на английский СО так что тут лучше перевести ответ чем намекать на дубль.

Comment: постораюсь перевести, если поможет

Comment: @Naumov я понял, что там решения проблемы через отдельную функцию. Мне это не нужно, я могу решить. Мне интересно почему он не ловит. И можно ли сделать так, чтобы он ловил?

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev он не ловит потому что в php, try...catch обрабатывает исключения, а notice это ошибка.

Comment: @Naumov А есть такой, чтобы ловил ошибки?))

Comment: Установить set_exception_handler и в callback'е функции кидать исключения с текстом ошибки номер строки и т.д. пример callback'а можете глянуть сдесь http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что try работает с **исключениями**. А notice - это сообщение об ошибке.

Для того чтобы РНР стал обрабатывать ошибки как исключения, надо настроить пользовательский обработчик ошибок, чтобы он начал выбрасывать исключения при ошибках. Самый простой будет выглядеть так:

```
set_error_handler(function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line) {
    throw new ErrorException ($err_msg, 0, $err_severity, $err_file, $err_line);
});
```

Если добавить этот код в начале РНР файла, то все ошибки начнут порождать исключения.

Можно также расширить этот код, сделав так, чтобы на ошибку каждого типа бросалось исключение отдельного типа.

Вот полноценный [готовый пример обработчика ошибок](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#code), который заворачивает ошибки в исключения и выводит их зависимости от настроек РНР

Answer (score -5):

Это решается просто в своем коде добавляете(условный пример)

```
if(!array_key_exists($x[5])) throw new Exception('Не найден ключ '.5.' в массиве $x');
```

а уже в исполняемом коде сможете отловить эту ошибку

дабы быть правильно понятым я прилагаю статью где подробно описывается метод отлавливания ошибок, написанная программистом в финансовой сфере [Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/264417/)

Comment: кстати notice - это вовсе не ошибка :) Это предупреждение

Comment: рекомендую вышеописанный код ставить в функции либо в классе, а уже при вызове функции или класса отлавливать